# Subset an igraph object for the name of the edge

Tags: r, subset, igraph

Consider a data frame that correlated each variable from with each other:

```
iris_cor <- structure(list(x = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Length", 
"Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Width", 
"Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Width", "Petal.Width", 
"Petal.Width"), y = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Width"), r = c(NA, -0.117569784133002, 0.871753775886583, 
0.817941126271576, -0.117569784133002, NA, -0.42844010433054, 
-0.366125932536439, 0.871753775886583, -0.42844010433054, NA, 
0.962865431402796, 0.817941126271576, -0.366125932536439, 0.962865431402796, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("x", "y", "r"))
```

If I wanted to make a network plot of this I would do the following:

```
library(igraph)
iris_igraph <- graph_from_data_frame(iris_cor)
```

Now if I were only interested in the correlations that involved with `Sepal.Length` I am unclear on how to efficiently extract that information. Trying both of these approaches is not successful. The first because of the error and the second because I only get the first instance of `Sepal.Length` not all of them:

```
> subgraph.edges(iris_igraph, E(iris_igraph)[name == "Sepal.Length"])
Error in eval(x$expr, data, x$env) : object 'name' not found
> 
> subgraph.edges(iris_igraph, V(iris_igraph)[name == "Sepal.Length"])
IGRAPH dc7408b DN-- 1 1 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), r (e/n)
+ edge from dc7408b (vertex names):
[1] Sepal.Length->Sepal.Length
```

This results in the desired output:

```
subgraph.edges(iris_igraph, E(iris_igraph)[1:4])
```

However a numbered index is not practical when the desired subsets of the igraph object aren't in order or there are many nodes/edges.

Can anyone recommend a way to subset an igraph object for the name of the edge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [indexing edge sequences](http://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph-es-indexing.html), you can use the special function `inc` for edges subsetting, which:

*takes a vertex sequence, and selects all edges that have at least one incident vertex in the vertex sequence.*

```
E(iris_igraph)[inc('Sepal.Length')]
#+ 7/16 edges (vertex names):
#[1] Sepal.Length->Sepal.Length Sepal.Length->Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length->Petal.Length
#[4] Sepal.Length->Petal.Width  Sepal.Width ->Sepal.Length Petal.Length->Sepal.Length
#[7] Petal.Width ->Sepal.Length
```

Select edges from `Sepal.Length`:

```
E(iris_igraph)[from('Sepal.Length')]
#+ 4/16 edges (vertex names):
#[1] Sepal.Length->Sepal.Length Sepal.Length->Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length->Petal.Length
#[4] Sepal.Length->Petal.Width
```

Select edges to `Sepal.Length`:

```
E(iris_igraph)[to('Sepal.Length')]
#+ 4/16 edges (vertex names):
#[1] Sepal.Length->Sepal.Length Sepal.Width ->Sepal.Length Petal.Length->Sepal.Length
#[4] Petal.Width ->Sepal.Length
```